# Table Content is not getting aligned

Tags: html, css

The content of HTML Table is not setting properly. And I tried all the possible methods I am still not able to solve it.
Please have a look.

```
.abc{
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #f2f2f2 ;
padding: 20px;
opacity: 0.8;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 45%;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;

}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

td {
background-color: #ffa64d;
color: black;

}
<h1><samp>Student Details</samp></h1>
<p> <%= link_to "Add new record", new_user_path %></p>
<table border=3>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>SecondName</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<table border=3>
<tr>
   <td><%= user.firstname%></td>
   <td><%= user.lastname%></td>
   <td><%= user.address %></td>
   <td><%= link_to "Delete",user,:method =>:delete,
  data:{:confirm => 'Are you Sure?'} %><br><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: please provide fiddle ?

Comment: "The content of HTML Table is not setting properly" — What table? You haven't provided any HTML. What does "properly" mean in this context?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aniket5689/0hj1fyew/

Comment: @AniketMainkar — Provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Describe your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aniket5689/0hj1fyew/1/

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the extra `<table>` tag you have given in table before defining the second Just remove that extra table tag

```css
.abc{
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #f2f2f2 ;
padding: 20px;
opacity: 0.8;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 45%;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;

}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

td {
background-color: #ffa64d;
color: black;

}
```

```html
<h1><samp>Student Details</samp></h1>
<p> <%= link_to "Add new record", new_user_path %></p>
<table border=3>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>SecondName</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
   <td><%= user.firstname%></td>
   <td><%= user.lastname%></td>
   <td><%= user.address %></td>
   <td><%= link_to "Delete",user,:method =>:delete,
  data:{:confirm => 'Are you Sure?'} %><br><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks.
Solved the problem.
Shifted table and end tags which was causing the problem.

Answer (score -2):

don't know what you're trying to achieve, but from what i see from your code, i think this is what you looking for:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

i hope this helps

Comment: "don't know what you're trying to achieve" — That suggests you really shouldn't be trying to answer the question.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` — That's the default for tables, so it is unlikely to do anything at all.

Comment: See the alignment of columns they are not in the same.
I have updated the fiddle again.

Comment: run the code and you will see that the row fields and columns doesnt match
and it looks like Bricks.